# Python - Reading through the same file from different starting lines

Tags: python

I am trying to read a `.non` file (you can find an example [here](https://github.com/mikix/nonogram-db/blob/master/db/webpbn/1.non)).
Those files contains 4 keys: width, height, rows and columns (both are made of multiple values).

Width and Height are ALWAYS before Rows, Columns or in my case Goal, thus I have to go through the file while not knowing when I'll find what I need.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
# This function will create the grid
def fcreate(grid_id):
    gridfile = open(grid_id['grid'], "r")
    # Here, we're going through the entire file, getting the values we need.
    # Still working on a pretty way to make the dictionary !
    for line in gridfile:
        if "width" in line:
            grid_id['width'] = re.sub('[A-z]', '', line).strip()
        if "height" in line:
            grid_id['height'] = re.sub('[A-z]', '', line).strip()
        if "rows" in line:
            # Get all the rows values until something else ? Or EOF
        if "columns" in line:
            # Get all the columns values until something else ? Or EOF
    # end of the for
    gridfile.close()
    return grid_id
    pass
```

`Grid_id` contains all the values I have to get.

I've tried making a new for in the "if "rows"", a while and whatnot, but can't seem to escape either reading through the entire file again or looping on the line that contains "rows" or "columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the indexes of the "rows" and "columns" lines then use these values to get the rows and column values.
You can do the following like that:

```
lines = gridfile.readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if "width" in line:
        grid_id['width'] = re.sub('[A-z]', '', line).strip()
    if "height" in line:
        grid_id['height'] = re.sub('[A-z]', '', line).strip()
    if "rows" in line:
        idx_rows = i
    if "columns" in line:
        idx_cols = i

width = int(grid_id['width'])
height = int(grid_id['height'])
rows = lines[idx_rows+1:idx_rows+1+height]
cols = lines[idx_cols+1:idx_cols+1+width]
```